# Why would this "off-topic" flag be disputed

Tags: support, questions, moderation

Fisrt let me begin with "sure the question has been asked many times" and I get that, but I think each case is it's own, so still asking.

So I recently flagged ( because I can't close vote yet ) [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31475203/exporting-data-from-oracle-to-mongodb-programatically-with-java) as being "off-topic". Not only that but I also took the time to explain ( i thought, reasonably ) the ways in which their questions was "off-topic" for both:

- Essentially asking for recomendations for tools
- Or then the basic subject of translating "SQL relational" to "Object or Document store database"

Now "though" the OP did actually make an edit to show a basically "flat" single table example, the actual "tone" of the question does not change. Furthermore, the additional comments from the OP ask again for recomendations of tools.

There is at least [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31476283/5031275) posted at present, which of course does little more than endorse "tools" and/or give resourses where to search for them.

Am I wrong in thinking the "disputed" reason here was because there was an answer, and/or an upvoted one. Or is there something my mind cannot wrap around that makes this a valid question suitable for this programming Q&A?

Newb here and not even sure about the chosen tags.

Comment: Yep, off-topic. No research, no clear question. Classic leecher. It might have been disputed because of the latest edit or bad luck with the queue.

Comment: @runDOSrun Thanks for the endorsement. I guess linked duplicate explains it to me though. *"tough luck, no-one could be bothered to look at or endorse"*. Which is disappointing. Suppose I'll endorse that if there is nothing better to say.

Comment: No, it's not that no one looked at it. It was marked disputed because someone (*not* a moderator) reviewed it and chose "Looks OK". In fact, three of the four reviewers did so.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Well, the close vote queue is far from perfect. It's large and the question seems to be ok at first glance (clear formatting, code example). People might have decided a bit too fast.

Comment: @MichaelMyers **That** does actually clarify more than the link. Have to admit, it's about my bedtime so about to retire. But another "disappointing" thing here is what I noticed under 2k rep is "most" reviewers only had "just over" 2k rep, and had been around for a lot longer. So i submitted "edits" ( with common sense ) several times just to get them through. So "should these people really be reviewing?". It's a much larger question I guess. Suppose I should just accept it. No other choice really.

Comment: @runDOSrun this is coming out of the triage review not the close vote queue.

Comment: @NathanOliver Just caught me before I closed my eyes. No "queue". This was a posted question I saw through a tag filter originally. I don' think it raised any flags otherwise. It's just "off-topic" in many ways. Anyhow. It seems there has been a fair judgement now.

Comment: @BlakesSeven Yes you were not in the triage queue but the votes that wound up disputing your flag more than likely did.

Comment: @NathanOliver Sorry.Drowsy. But is there a difference in this to what "Micheal Myers" ( love that name ) said before. Just for my own clarification, becuase I'd like to understand it. I'll read in the morning.

Comment: @BlakesSeven choosing `"Looks OK"` is in the triage review.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think you misunderstood the point of this post. Anyhow, it's done now.

Comment: runDOSrun thought Michael Myers was referring to the close vote queue when they said that 3 non-mod reviewers said the question "Looks OK". NathanOliver was just pointing out that Michael was referring to the Triage queue, not the close vote queue.